# Signature matches another specific subroutine that shares the same assignment generic binding (but it doesn't)

Tags: fortran

I am migrating from ifort14 to ifort16, on 14 the code compiles and runs fine on 16 I get a compile time error which makes no sense to me. Long story short the compiler complains about a procedure whose definition is the last in the file and if I change the order it will complain about a different procedure, again the one that comes last. The error does not make any sense and this behaviour does not make sense either. Does this sound familiar to someone and do you have any idea where I could look for the problem?

I have the following structure

File1:

```
module model_generic
implicit none

   type, abstract :: modelGen

           logical, public :: init_flag = .false.

           contains

                   procedure         :: isInit   => dispInitFlag_model
                   procedure, nopass :: taylorRule_func
                   procedure, nopass :: penalty_func

   end type modelGen

   contains

   function dispInitFlag_model(this) result(init_flag)

           class(modelGen), intent(in) :: this
           logical                     :: init_flag

           init_flag = this%init_flag

   end function dispInitFlag_model

end module model_generic
```

File2:

```
module model_nk_generic
   use model_generic
   implicit none

   type, abstract, extends(modelGen) :: model_nk

           logical, public :: init_flag_nk = .false.

                   contains

                   procedure :: isInit       => dispInitFlag_model_nk
                   procedure :: setIniGuess  => setIniGuess_model_nk_default

           ! deferred procedures
                   procedure(obj_func),            deferred :: lossFunction
                   procedure(IS_PC_curves),        deferred :: IS_PC0
                   procedure(Taylor_IS_PC_curves), deferred :: taylor_IS_PC
                   procedure(IS_curve),            deferred :: IS
                   procedure(PC_curve),            deferred :: PC
                   procedure(R_trans),             deferred :: R_lom
                   procedure(A_trans),             deferred :: A_lom
                   procedure(eps_trans),           deferred :: eps_lom

                   generic :: IS_PC   =>   IS_PC0, taylor_IS_PC

   end type model_nk

   abstract interface
      ! omitted
   end interface

   contains

   function dispInitFlag_model_nk(this) result(init_flag_nk)

           class(model_nk), intent(in) :: this
           logical                     :: init_flag_nk

           init_flag_nk = this%init_flag_nk

   end function dispInitFlag_model_nk

   subroutine setIniGuess_model_nk_default(this,VFonGrid,grid)

           class(model_nk),               intent(in)            :: this
           real(KIND=DP), dimension(:),   intent(out)           :: VFonGrid
           real(KIND=DP), dimension(:,:), intent(in), optional  :: grid

           VFonGrid = 0e0
           !VFonGrid = 1._DP

   end subroutine setIniGuess_model_nk_default

end module model_nk_generic
```

The error I receive during compilation (the above is compiled as a part of a bigger project) is

```
error #8437: The type/rank signature for the arguments of this specific
subroutine matches another specific subroutine that shares the same 
ASSIGNMENT generic binding.
end subroutine setIniGuess_model_nk_default
^
```

The procedure (or its binding name) does not appear anywhere else in the programme except one module where it is called (I grepped for it to be sure). Thus it cannot share any generic binding. When I delete it the compiler gives me the same error with the `dispInitFlag_model_nk` procedure. When I add a `do_nothing` procedure then it will complain about that one. The compiler seems to always complain about the last procedure in the file.

A minimalistic test case like below compiles fine (using the same makefile). Another code without any OOP features compiles fine too.

```
program main
   use model_generic
   use model_nk_generic

   class(model_nk), allocatable :: svars

end program main
```

Every time I do a clean compilation, all libraries that I use I compile from source except MKL but that should be linked correctly I have checked that.

Does any one have any idea what could be wrong with the source file or with my compiling environment?

**Edit1:** Forgot to mention the compiler flags. Normally I use `ifort -openmp -O3` but I also tried my usual set of debugging flags `ifort -openmp -g -p -traceback -check bounds -ftrapuv -fpe0 -O0 -warn -check uninit -gen-interfaces -warn interfaces -check all` and I tried with and without the `-openmp` flag. At some point the compiler told me the flag was deprecated but using `-qopenmp` instead did not change things.

**Edit2:** Probably I should also have mentioned that I also use the preprocessor. And both files are preprocessed. But again on v14 it works fine and the error occurs in file2 after file1 (its dependency) is compiled.

Comment: What happens with ifort v17?  What command line options are you using?

Comment: Possibly some interpretation has changed for newer ifort versions...?

Comment: @IanH Right, I forgot to mention the flags. I used `ifort -openmp -O3`, I have also tried `ifort -openmp -g -p traceback =check bounds -ftrapuv -fpe0 -O0 -warn` and I tried with and without `-openmp`. I can't find it now but yesterday the compiler was telling me that the `-openmp` flag is deprecated and I should use `-qopenmp` if I remember correctly. But deprecated does not mean broken plus I tried it and of course that did not change anything. I will add the flags to the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @IanH I cannot use v17 as I do not have the license. It is installed on the cluster but I get a license error. Possibly we have a small number of licences and I was unlucky that it was checked out. I tried to install evaluation copy on my laptop but it requires 4GB of space and there is no way how I could get that. I have another machine on which I could install it but I will need to install a linux box in VM first and it is unlikely I will have time for this anytime soon. I will report back if by any chance I can get v17 working.

Comment: @roygvib If that is the case how to investigate? What do you think I should be looking for? But the newer versions should be backwards compatible, shouldn't they? One of my thoughts was that I was perhaps mixing different conflicting modules but I looked into that and didn't find anything.

Comment: I just looked at a page like this https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/607462 Also, the interpretation of automatic reallocation of LHS seems to have been changed from ifort17 (so as to conform to the Standards) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/AbFsEX9-e-s so things may be tricky... After all, I guess making an MWE that reproduces the error will be most useful.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with a compilable variant of your code.  Without a complete compilable example not much more can be said.  If it is a compiler problem (and the symptoms make that quite possible) trying the latest version (and also the most recent update to 16) is the obvious suggestion.  For this sort of issue you are better off posting at the [relevant Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/) or going through their premier support, if you have access to that.

Comment: That the behavior changes with the routine order sounds more like a compiler bug, but it could be, as others have said, more strict error checking. I would encourage you to provide a complete buildable example that shows the error and post it in the Intel user forum.